# antMatchers allow ADMIN all routes while other roles are restricted

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Specific user groups should have access to different api-routes. Given the following `HttpSecurity` we, for example, allow `CUSTOMER` to access `GET /invoices/*`. Also, I want to allow `ADMIN` to access any route `/**`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http = http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable(); // REST only

    // ### Authentication
    // ...

    // ### Authorization

    // anonymous (and all other roles)
    e = e
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                    "/user/account/create",
                    "/user/account/confirm/*",
                    "/feedback")
            .permitAll()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/" + StorageController.STORAGE_RELATIVE_PATH, // public files
                    "/translations/*")
            .permitAll();

    // role CUSTOMER
    e = e
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/invoices",
                    "/invoices/*")
            .hasRole(Role.CUSTOMER.toString())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,
                    "/profile",
                    "/contracts/billingAddress")
            .hasRole(Role.CUSTOMER.toString())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                    "/contracts",
                    "/profile/logo")
            .hasRole(Role.CUSTOMER.toString());

    // only ADMIN
    e = e.antMatchers("/**").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.toString());
}
```

While `ADMIN` is allowed to use all non-mentioned `/admin/.../` routes, the role get's a `403` on, for example, `/invoices/*` - why? From what I understand the specified configuration depends on the order and hence requires `/invoices/*` to have `CUSTOMER` role and hence `ADMIN` is not enough - correct?

If I add the following (section `CUSTOMER or ADMIN`), it works, but it is so cumbersome to always list `ADMIN` role. I just want `ADMIN`s to be able to access everything.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    // role CUSTOMER
    e = e
            // ... as above ...


    // CUSTOMER or ADMIN
    e = e
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/invoices/*") // AGAIN
            .hasAnyRole(Role.CUSTOMER.toString(),
                    Role.ADMIN.toString());

    // only ADMIN
    e = e.antMatchers("/**").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.toString());
}
```

Also, I cannot put the `ADMIN` rule above the others, because it would exclude the other roles from accessing anything. Is there a way to specify what I want to do in a more elegant/easier way?

Comment: Basically, I want to tell a role and then list all allowed routes; but instead I feel forced to list the routes and for each say what roles may access them. The latter feels cumbersome.

Comment: In the end I feel that the approach as given is a bad design. Either we should decide to group the routes semantically to the endpoint (e.g. all /invoices/** routes) and tell what role may access which specific route or group by role and tell what routes they may access (but I feel this is not supported?!). But the given approach is a mess that tries to minimize the code for configuration. It, however, is not easy to maintain.

Comment: DId you try to invert e.antMatchers("/**").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.toString()); to be the first matcher that appears?

Comment: what do you mean by inverting? Just putting the rule first gives all other roles 403s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated in your question, this behaviour occurs because each matcher is considered in the order it was declared.

A request to `/invoices` will reach the below matcher first and since it is a match, it will apply the associated rule.

```
.antMatchers("/invoices").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
```

If the user making the request only has the role `"ADMIN"` then they will be denied access, because an `"ADMIN"` is not a `"CUSTOMER"`.

**Option 1**

To get the desired behaviour you can explicitly list out the roles that have access to the endpoint.

As you mentioned, this is verbose, however, the advantage is that it clearly indicates the allowed roles in one place.

```
.antMatchers("/invoices").hasAnyRole("CUSTOMER", "ADMIN")
```

**Option 2**

If an `"ADMIN"` should be able to do anything a `"CUSTOMER"` can do, then you can declare a `RoleHierarchy` that states that any `"ADMIN"` is also a `"CUSTOMER"`.

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    hierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_CUSTOMER");
    return hierarchy;
}
```

The `>` symbol can be thought of as meaning "includes".

Then, any endpoints protected by `.hasRole("CUSTOMER")` can also be accessed by users with the role `"ADMIN"`, since having the role `"ADMIN"` implies that they also have the role `"CUSTOMER"`.